# Looking to apply cookies property to jQuery checkbox script

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

First of all, what my script does is allow me to swap divs by using a checkbox.

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yHTFF/8/

I'm seeking help with setting up cookies properly for this script. I'd like to set this up so that the div and checkbox the user leaves it at remains the same upon page reload.

Here's my script:

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="ontopic_posts">
    Content 1
</div>
<div id="offtopic_posts" style="display: none;">
    Content 2
</div>

<input id="cbox_posts" type="checkbox"> show off-topics

<!--JQUERY-->
<script>
jQuery("#cbox_posts").click(function() {
  if ( jQuery(this).is(':checked') )
  {
    jQuery("#offtopic_posts").show();
    jQuery("#ontopic_posts").hide();
  }
  else
  {
    jQuery("#offtopic_posts").hide();
    jQuery("#ontopic_posts").show();
  }  
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could give a more detailed error report than "not working". *What* isn't working? [Does this script work?](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSaU/) Finally, what do you know about cookies? What have you tried so far?

Comment: My apologies. The divs do not swap in IE. Checking or unchecking the box does not do anything, it does not swap the divs like it does in FF/Chrome/Saf. Also, I don't know much about java or cookies, I haven't tried anything.

Comment: I fixed the IE issue. Just had to update jQuery from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1.

Still seeking help with setting up cookies properly for this script. I'd like to set this up so that the div and checkbox the user leaves it at remains the same upon page reload.

Answer (score 1):

You attach the event handler before the element exists.

Move the `script` tag after the input or wrap the script with [`$(document).ready`.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Oops, I do have the script tag following the input. I just mixed up the snippet here.

Comment: I fixed the IE issue. Just had to update jQuery from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1. Thanks for your assistance though! It's much appreciated.